# The view account.views.updatedata didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead

Tags: html, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I have an issue with my update button and it show this error to me when I click the update button, it is suppose to redirect me to the next page where the staff can update the details, how do I fix that error, so that it can redirect me to the next page where it will show the forms for the staff to update the details

The error I had is shown below here (Traceback error):

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/updatedata/21/

Django Version: 3.1.4
Python Version: 3.8.0
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'account.apps.AccountConfig',
 'crispy_forms',
 'channels']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django_session_timeout.middleware.SessionTimeoutMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\TAY\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\TAY\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 186, in _get_response
    self.check_response(response, callback)
  File "C:\Users\TAY\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 307, in check_response
    raise ValueError(

Exception Type: ValueError at /updatedata/21/
Exception Value: The view account.views.updatedata didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.
```

views.py

```
@login_required()
def updatedata(request, id):
    photo = get_object_or_404(Photo, id=id)
    if request.method == 'POST':  # check for the post request body
        form = UpdateForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('/logdata')

        else:
            msg = 'form is not valid'  # Show an error message if the form is not valid
    else:
        form = UpdateForm()
        context = {
            "form": form,
            "photo": photo

        }
        return render(request, 'updatedata.html', context)
```

logdata.html

```
        {% extends "home.html" %}
    {% block content %}
    <style>
    table {
        border-collapse:separate;
        border:solid black 1px;
        border-radius:6px;
        -moz-border-radius:6px;
    }
    
    td, th {
        border-left:solid black 1px;
        border-top:solid black 1px;

    }


    
    th {

        border-top: none;
    }
    
    td:first-child, th:first-child {
         border-left: none;
          width: 180px;

    }

    .pagination a {
    padding: 10px;
    }

    .sort {
    display: inline;
    margin: 0 20px 0 20px;
    }


    ul.pagination li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 5px 15px;
    }


    ul.pagination li.active {
    padding: 5px 15px;
    background-color: hsla(199, 34%, 55%, 1);
    border-radius: 30px;
    color: white;
    }

    ul.pagination li.disabled {
    padding: 5px 15px;
    }

    ul.pagination li {
    display: block;
    //border: 1px solid hsla(199, 34%, 64%, 0.74);
    }

    ul.pagination li a:hover,
    ul.pagination li a:active {
    border-radius: 30px;
    background-color: hsla(199, 34%, 64%, 0.74);
    }

    @media only screen and (min-width: 268px) {
    ul.pagination {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: left;
    align-items: right;
    font-size: 18px;
    }


    </style>
    <script>
      
    
     // Function to download table data into csv file
            function download_table_as_csv(table_id, separator = ',') {
                var rows = document.querySelectorAll('table#' + table_id + ' tr');
                var csv = [];
                for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
                    var row = [], cols = rows[i].querySelectorAll('td, th');
                    for (var j = 0; j < cols.length; j++) {
                        var data = cols[j].innerText.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm, '').replace(/(\s\s)/gm, ' ')
                        data = data.replace(/"/g, '""');
                        row.push('"' + data + '"');
                    }
                    csv.push(row.join(separator));
                }
                var csv_string = csv.join('\n');
                var filename = 'export_' + table_id + '_' + new Date().toLocaleDateString() + '.csv';
                var link = document.createElement('a');
                link.style.display = 'none';
                link.setAttribute('target', '_blank');
                link.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(csv_string));
                link.setAttribute('download', filename);
                document.body.appendChild(link);
                link.click();
                document.body.removeChild(link);
            };

    </script>


       <div style="padding-left:16px">
         <br>
    
    
     <div class="form-block">
         <h6>Search for Part Number/ Serial Number/ Reception Number/ MCO Number/ Customer Name/ Current Status</h6>
        <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0" action="{% url 'logdata' %}" method='GET' value='{{ request.GET.q }}'>
            <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search" name="q" value='{{ request.GET.q }}'/>
            <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
        </form>

      <div class="sort">
           <h5 class="col-md-3">Sort By : </h5>


                <div id="sortBlock" class="col-md-9">
                    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0" action="" method='GET' value='{{ request.GET.sortType }}'>

                    <div class="sort">
                        <input type="radio" id="partno" name="sortType" value="partno">
                        <label for="partno">Part Number</label>
                    </div>

                     <div class="sort">
                        <input type="radio" id="serialno" name="sortType" value="serialno">
                        <label for="serialno">Serial Number</label>
                    </div>



                    <div class="sort">
                        <input type="radio" id="mcoNum" name="sortType" value="mcoNum">
                        <label for="mcoNum">MCO Number</label>
                    </div>

                    <div class="sort">
                        <input type="radio" id="Customername" name="sortType" value="Customername">
                        <label for="Customername">Customer Name</label>
                    </div>
                         <div class="sort">
                        <input type="Submit" value="Sort"/>
                    </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
         </div>
         <br>
       <table id="viewTable" class="m-2">
            <i class="fa fa-download" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                <a href="#" onclick="download_table_as_csv('viewTable');">Download as CSV</a>
           <br>
    
      <tr class="header">
        <th>Latest Log</th>
          <th>Part Number</th>
          <th>Serial Number</th>
          <th>Reception Number</th>
          <th>MCO Number</th>
          <th>Customer Name</th>
          <th>Current Status</th>
          <th>Next Status</th>
          <th>Action</th>
      </tr>
           {% for photo in allusername %}
    
    
      <tr>
            <td>{{photo.Datetime}}</td>
          <td>{{photo.partno}}</td>
          <td>{{photo.serialno}}</td>
          <td>{{photo.reception}}</td>
          <td>{{photo.mcoNum}}</td>
          <td>{{photo.Customername}}</td>
          <td>{{photo.status}}</td>
          <td>{{photo.nextstatus}}</td>



          <td>
          <form action="{% url 'logdetails' photo.id %}" method="post">
              {% csrf_token %}
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-info">View</button>
          </form>
          </td>


           <td>
          <form action="{% url 'updatedata' photo.id %}" method="post">
              {% csrf_token %}
          <button type="submit" name="update_staff_page" class="btn btn-sm btn-info">Update</button>
</form>
    
    {% endfor %}
    
    </table>
         <br>

  {% if allusername.has_other_pages %}

  <ul class="pagination pr-3 mr-1 ml-auto">

    {% if allusername.has_previous %}
      <li><a href="?q={{ query|urlencode }}&sortType={{ order_by }}&page={{ allusername.previous_page_number }}">&laquo;</a></li>
    {% else %}
      <li class="disabled"><span>&laquo;</span></li>
    {% endif %}
    {% for i in allusername.paginator.page_range %}
      {% if allusername.number == i %}
        <li class="active"><span>{{ i }} <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></span></li>
      {% else %}
        <li><a href="?q={{ query|urlencode }}&sortType={{ order_by }}&page={{ i }}">{{ i }}</a></li>
      {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
    {% if allusername.has_next %}
      <li><a href="?q={{ query|urlencode }}&sortType={{ order_by }}&page={{ allusername.next_page_number }}">&raquo;</a></li>
    {% else %}
      <li class="disabled"><span>&raquo;</span></li>
    {% endif %}
    </ul>
    {% endif %}

    </div>
       </div>

{% endblock %}
```

forms.py

```
class UpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    mcoNum = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.TextInput(
            attrs={

                "class": "form-control"
            }
        )
    )
    reception = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.TextInput(
            attrs={
                "class": "form-control"
            }
        )
    )
    partno = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.TextInput(
            attrs={
                "class": "form-control"
            }
        )
    )

    serialno = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.TextInput(
            attrs={
                "class": "form-control"
            }
        )
    )

    Customername = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.TextInput(
            attrs={
                "class": "form-control"
            }
        )
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Photo
        fields = ("mcoNum", "reception", "partno", "serialno")

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(UpdateForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.fields['mcoNum'].required = False
        self.fields['reception'].required = False
        self.fields['partno'].required = False
        self.fields['serialno'].required = False
```

updatedata.html

```
<!doctype html>
{% extends "home.html" %}
{% block content %}
{% load static %}

<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <style>
      .button {
  background-color: #38d39f;
  border-color: #38d39f;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 16px;
  width: 275px;
}
    </style>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'fonts/icomoon/style.css' %}">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/owl.carousel.min.css' %}">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.min.css' %}">

    <!-- Style -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/style.css' %}">

  </head>
{% if messages %}
{% for message in messages %}
<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
    <button type = "button" class="close" data-dismiss = "alert">x</button>
    {{ message }}
</div>
{% endfor %}
{% endif %}

   <div style="padding-left:16px">
       <table class="first" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
         <tr>
           <h5>Current Log Data</h5>
         </tr>
         <br>
           <tr>
               <th>MCO Number: {{photo.mcoNum}}</th>
           </tr>

             <tr>
               <th>Reception Number: {{photo.reception}}</th>
           </tr>

           <tr>
               <th>Part Number: {{photo.partno}}</th>

           </tr>
           <tr>
               <th>Serial Number: {{photo.serialno}}</th>
           </tr>
           <tr>
               <th>Customer Name: {{photo.Customername}}</th>
           </tr>


</table>

  <div class="content">
    <div class="container">

      <div class="row justify-content-center">

        <div class="col-md-6 contents">
          <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-md-25">
                  <a href="{% url 'logdata' %}" class="btn btn-dark my-3">Go Back</a>

              <div class="form-block">
                  <div class="mb-3">
                </div>

              <h2>Update Log Data</h2>
                <br/>
                <form method="post">
                  {% csrf_token %}
                  <br>
                    <div class="form-group first">
                    <label for="MCO">MCO Number</label>
                      {{ form.mcoNum }}
                  </div>
                  <br>

                  <div class="form-group last mb-4">
                    <label for="Reception">Reception Number</label>
                      {{ form.reception }}
                  </div>
                  <br>
                  <div class="form-group last mb-4">
                    <label for="partno">Part Number</label>
                      {{ form.partno }}
                  </div>
                  <br>
                  <div class="form-group last mb-4">
                    <label for="serialno">Serial Number</label>
                      {{ form.serialno }}
                  </div>
                  <br>
                  <div class="form-group last mb-4">
                    <label for="Customername">Customer Name</label>
                      {{ form.Customername }}
                  </div>
                  <button class="button" >Submit</button>

                  <br>
                </form>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


    <script src="{% static 'js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/popper.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/main.js' %}"></script>
   </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

change your view into this

views.py

```
from django.http import Http404
from django.contrib import messages

@login_required()
def updatedata(request, id):
    try:
        photo = Photo.objects.get(id=id)
        if request.method == 'POST' and 'update_staff' not in request.POST:  # check for the post request body
            form = UpdateForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                form.save()
                return redirect('/logdata')
            else:
                messages.add_message(request, messages.ERROR, 'form is not valid') # Show an error message if the form is not valid
        else:
            form = UpdateForm(instance=photo)
            context = {
                "form": form,
                "photo": photo
            }
        return render(request, 'updatedata.html', context)
    except Exception as e:
        raise Http404
```

and your template into this

logdata.html

```
<form action="{% url 'updatedata' photo.id %}" method="post">
              {% csrf_token %}
          <button type="submit" name="update_staff_page" class="btn btn-sm btn-info">Update</button>
</form>
```

i think you not make clear statement, if the post don't send any data on method post you submit

Comment: Thanks, this help me, but right now I have an issue is that when the staff only wants to change 1 of the textbox and when they click submit, the rest of the data went blank, how do i solve this issue so that only 1 of the data will be change and the rest of the data remains the same and won't go blank

Comment: can you provide me the detail template input form? because example your logdata.html is just form and button only, not with input form

Comment: sure, let me update it

Comment: ok, i have updatt it already

Comment: done, i have update my views.py version, can you try it

Comment: Hi, I got this error: The view account.views.updatedata didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.
after i change to your updated views.py

Comment: can you provide me detail error before The view account.views.updatedata didn't return an HttpResponse object?

Comment: Hi, I added the new traceback error already

Comment: Hi, sorry i recently updated the views.py again, you can try it